# Dapper with existing database and weird naming convention

Tags: asp.net, dapper

im using asp.net core 2.0 with dapper. My table looks like:

```
N_ORDER (ID)
CREATION_DATE
N_STATUS_INT
```

So, my model i had to create like:

```
public int N_ORDER { get; set; }
public DateTime CREATION_DATE { get; set;} and etc.
```

Is there any way to avoid this naming convention on my model as if i was using EF Core with FluentAPI? So i can name my model correctly? eq:

```
        this.Property(c => c.OrderId).HasColumnName("N_ORDER");
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you not use column aliases in your query? Ex: `SELECT N_ORDER AS OrderId FROM Orders`

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, and the feature is called "Custom Mapping". In brief you can specify how to map columns names to object properties using the `SetTypeMap` method. `SetTypeMap` needs a `CustomTypeMapper` object as parameter.

If it is ok for you to use a Dapper extension, the Dapper-FluentMap hides all the complexity:

https://github.com/henkmollema/Dapper-FluentMap

More details on both the options in this article I wrote on the subject:

https://medium.com/dapper-net/custom-columns-mapping-1cd45dfd51d6